# Speed up react site initial loading

Tags: javascript, node.js, iis, webpack, gzip

I am building a React site and I am not sure I got the compiling right because it takes about 5 seconds just to load the libraries the first time (after that it is cached so it's faster).
I need help to find what I am doing wrong and slows down the load time.

I am posting here the files I am using.

package.json

```
{
 "name": "MySite",
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "description": "Something",
 "private": true,
 "devDependencies": {
  "babel-plugin-react-html-attrs": "^2.0.0",
  "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
  "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
  "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
  "babili-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.2",
  "compression-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0",
  "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.1",
  "react-scripts": "1.0.10",
  "serve-favicon": "^2.4.3",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.1",
  "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.2"
 },
 "dependencies": {
  "ajv": "^5.2.2",
  "axios": "^0.16.2",
  "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
  "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
  "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
  "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
  "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
  "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
  "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
  "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.3.13",
  "circular-dependency-plugin": "^3.0.0",
  "classnames": "^2.2.5",
  "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.16",
  "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
  "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
  "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
  "es6-promise": "^4.1.1",
  "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
  "firebase": "^4.1.3",
  "history": "^4.6.3",
  "immutable": "^3.8.1",
  "invariant": "^2.2.2",
  "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
  "jsdom": "^11.1.0",
  "jsonwebtoken": "^7.4.1",
  "konva": "^1.6.3",
  "less": "^2.3.1",
  "less-loader": "^4.0.5",
  "react": "^15.6.1",
  "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.6.0",
  "react-async-script": "^0.9.1",
  "react-async-script-loader": "^0.3.0",
  "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.1",
  "react-dnd": "^2.4.0",
  "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^2.4.1",
  "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
  "react-fontawesome": "^1.6.1",
  "react-ga": "^2.2.0",
  "react-google-recaptcha": "^0.9.6",
  "react-gravatar": "^2.6.3",
  "react-helmet": "^5.1.3",
  "react-input-range": "^1.2.1",
  "react-konva": "^1.1.3",
  "react-modal": "^2.2.2",
  "react-page-click": "^4.0.1",
  "react-recaptcha": "^2.3.2",
  "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
  "react-router": "^3.0.2",
  "react-router-redux": "^4.0.0",
  "react-tag-input": "^4.7.2",
  "react-toggle": "^4.0.1",
  "redux": "^3.7.2",
  "redux-form": "^7.0.1",
  "redux-logger": "^2.3.2",
  "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
  "rimraf": "^2.6.1",
  "single-module-instance-webpack-plugin": "0.0.4",
  "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
  "superagent": "^3.5.2",
  "webpack": "^3.5.0",
  "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
  "xml2js": "^0.4.17",
  "xmldom": "^0.1.27",
  "xpath": "0.0.24"
 },
 "scripts": {
  "start": "node devServer.js --progress --verbose",
  "clean": "rimraf ./dist",
  "dev": "webpack -d --watch --progress --display-error-details --display-reasons",
  "start1": "webpack-dev-server  --config ./webpack.config.comphotdeploy -d --progress --colors --host localhost --port 28080 --hot --inline --content-base src",
  "builddev": "webpack -d --progress --display-error-details --display-reasons",
  "build": "webpack -p --progress --verbose",
  "dist": "rimraf ./dist&&webpack -d --display-error-details --display-reasons",
  "start-react": "SET PORT=9999&&SET DEVTOOL=source-map&&react-scripts start",
  "build-react": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
 },
 "eslintConfig": {
  "extends": "./node_modules/react-scripts/config/eslint.js"
 }
}
```

When I build to deploy online I am using the command

> npm run build

webpack.config.js

```
var BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var ProvidePlugin = require("webpack/lib/ProvidePlugin");
var CommonsChunkPlugin = require("webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin");
var LimitChunkCountPlugin = require("webpack/lib/optimize/LimitChunkCountPlugin");
var DedupePlugin = require("webpack/lib/optimize/DedupePlugin");
var SingleModuleInstancePlugin = require('single-module-instance-webpack-plugin');
var CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
var CircularDependencyPlugin = require('circular-dependency-plugin');

//var BUILD_DIR =  path.resolve(__dirname,'/opt/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/Client/html');
var BUILD_DIR =  path.resolve(__dirname,'dist');

var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');
var CLIENT_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client');

// Load environment variables from .env file. Suppress warnings using silent
// if this file is missing. dotenv will never modify any environment variables
// that have already been set.
// https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv
require('dotenv').config({silent: true});

var PrintChunksPlugin = function() {};
PrintChunksPlugin.prototype.apply = function(compiler) {
    compiler.plugin('compilation', function(compilation, params) {
        compilation.plugin('after-optimize-chunk-assets', function(chunks) {
            console.log(chunks.map(function(c) {
                return {
                    id: c.id,
                    name: c.name
/*,
                    includes: c.modules.map(function(m) {
                        return m.request;
                    })
*/
                };
            }));
        });
    });
};

var config = {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
    entry: {
        app: APP_DIR + '/index.js'
    },

    output: {
        path:BUILD_DIR,
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        sourceMapFilename: "[name].bundle.js.map",
        chunkFilename: "[name]-chunk.js",
        //publicPath: BUILD_DIR
    },

  watch: false,
  watchOptions: {
    poll: true,
    aggregateTimeout: 300,
    number: 1000
  },
  module : {
      loaders : [
          {
              test : /\.jsx?/,
              include : APP_DIR,
              exclude: /node_modules/,
              loaders: ['react-hot-loader', 'babel-loader?' + JSON.stringify({
                cacheDirectory: true,
                plugins: [
                  'transform-runtime',
                  'react-html-attrs',
                  'transform-class-properties',
                  'transform-decorators-legacy'
                ],
                presets: [
                    [
                        "es2015",
                        {
                            "modules": false
                        }
                        ],
                'react',
                'stage-2']
          })]
      },
      // CSS
      // "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
      // "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
      // "style" loader turns CSS into JS modules that inject <style> tags.
      // In production, we use a plugin to extract that CSS to a file, but
      // in development "style" loader enables hot editing of CSS.
      {
          test: /\.css$/,
          include: path.join(__dirname, 'src/style'),
          loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
      },
      // "file" loader makes sure those assets get served by WebpackDevServer.
      // When you `import` an asset, you get its (virtual) filename.
      // In production, they would get copied to the `build` folder.
      {
          test: /\.(ico|jpg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?.*)?$/,
          exclude: /\/favicon.ico$/,
          loader: 'file-loader',
          query: {
            name: '[path][name][hash].[ext]',
            publicPath: '/'
          }
      },
      {
          test: /\.(ico)(\?.*)?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: 'file-loader',
          query: {
              name: './images/[name].[ext]'
          }
      },
      {
          test: /\.xml$/,
          loader: 'file-loader',
          query: {
              name: './[name].[ext]'
          }
      },
  ]
  },

     // use EnableCircularDependencyPlugin=true|false to check the option
  plugins: (function() {
        var plugins = [
              new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                  // A common mistake is not stringifying the "production" string.
                  'process.env': { 'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production') },

                  // DISABLE redux-devtools HERE
                  __DEVTOOLS__: false 
              }),

            new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                { from: APP_DIR + '/index.html', to: BUILD_DIR + '/index.html' },
                { from: APP_DIR + '/sitemap.xml', to: BUILD_DIR + '/sitemap.xml' },
                { from: APP_DIR + '/Robots.txt', to: BUILD_DIR + '/Robots.txt' },
                { from: APP_DIR + '/images/favicon.ico', to: BUILD_DIR + '/images/favicon.ico' },
                { from: APP_DIR + '/images/favicon.png', to: BUILD_DIR + '/images/favicon.png' },
                { from: APP_DIR + '/images/favicon-16x16.png', to: BUILD_DIR + '/images/favicon-16x16.png' },
                { from: APP_DIR + '/images/favicon-32x32.png', to: BUILD_DIR + '/images/favicon-32x32.png' },
                { from: APP_DIR + '/images/favicon-48x48.png', to: BUILD_DIR + '/images/favicon-48x48.png' },
                { from: APP_DIR + '/images/favicon-57x57.png', to: BUILD_DIR + '/images/favicon-57x57.png' },
                { from: APP_DIR + '/images/favicon-60x60.png', to: BUILD_DIR + '/images/favicon-60x60.png' },
                { from: APP_DIR + '/images/favicon-72x72.png', to: BUILD_DIR + '/images/favicon-72x72.png' },
                { from: APP_DIR + '/images/favicon-76x76.png', to: BUILD_DIR + '/images/favicon-76x76.png' },
                { from: APP_DIR + '/images/favicon-96x96.png', to: BUILD_DIR + '/images/favicon-96x96.png' },
                { from: APP_DIR + '/images/favicon-114x114.png', to: BUILD_DIR + '/images/favicon-114x114.png' },
                { from: APP_DIR + '/images/favicon-120x120.png', to: BUILD_DIR + '/images/favicon-120x120.png' },
                { from: APP_DIR + '/images/favicon-144x144.png', to: BUILD_DIR + '/images/favicon-144x144.png' },
                { from: APP_DIR + '/images/favicon-152x152.png', to: BUILD_DIR + '/images/favicon-152x152.png' },
                { from: APP_DIR + '/images/favicon-160x160.png', to: BUILD_DIR + '/images/favicon-160x160.png' },
                { from: APP_DIR + '/images/favicon-180x180.png', to: BUILD_DIR + '/images/favicon-180x180.png' },
                { from: APP_DIR + '/images/favicon-192x192.png', to: BUILD_DIR + '/images/favicon-192x192.png' }
            ]),
            new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
            new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),

            new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({analyzerMode: 'static'}),
            //new PrintChunksPlugin()

            new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
                name: 'vendor',
                minChunks: function (module) {
                   // this assumes your vendor imports exist in the node_modules directory
                   return module.context && module.context.indexOf('node_modules') !== -1;
                }
            }),

            //CommonChunksPlugin will now extract all the common modules from vendor and main bundles
            new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
                name: 'manifest' //But since there are no more common modules between them we end up with just the runtime code included in the manifest file
            }),
        ];


        // HERE IS OPTION CONDITION
        // edit .env file change to EnableCircularDependencyPlugin=false will bypass it
        if (process.env.EnableCircularDependencyPlugin=="true") {
            plugins.push(new CircularDependencyPlugin({
                // exclude detection of files based on a RegExp
                exclude: /a\.js|node_modules/,
                // add errors to webpack instead of warnings
                failOnError: true
            }));
        }

        return plugins;
    })(),
    node: {
        net: 'empty',
    dns: 'empty'
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script src="manifest.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor.bundle.js" ></script>
        <script src="app.bundle.js" ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

After compiling I end up with the following files:

- vendor.bundle.js (Stat size: 3.94MB, Parsed size: 1.45MB, Gzipped size: 420.02KB)
- app.bundle.js (Stat size: 910.96KB, Parsed size: 459.62KB, Gzipped size: 89.2KB)
- A-chunk.js (Stat size: 652.29KB, Parsed size: 279.4KB, Gzipped size: 54.31KB)
- B-chunk.js (Stat size: 598.87KX, Parsed size: 257.76KB, Gzipped size: 51.04KB)

Another thing that is weird is that I can see in A-chunk.js some files that should only be in B-Chunk.js.

My guess is that it is vendo.bundle.js that slows down the initial loading because of its size.

The real files (the one that I deploy) are the size of Parsed size, not Gzipped size.
It looks like the gzip compression is not kicking in.

And that's where I am at a loss as to why it does not do it automatically.
Is there a command to do/add to get the gzipped files automatically or is it a step I should do manually?

---

Some progress.

In webpack.config.js I have added the following:

```
var CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');
```

and

```
new CompressionPlugin({
 asset: "[path].gz[query]",
 algorithm: "gzip",
 test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
 threshold: 10240,
 minRatio: 0.8
})
```

So now I have the js and js.gz files generated.

I also updated my web.config to add the following:

```
  <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
    <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"/>
    <dynamicTypes>
      <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
      <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
      <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
      <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
    </dynamicTypes>
    <staticTypes>
      <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
      <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
      <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
      <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
    </staticTypes>
  </httpCompression>
  <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true"/>
```

But that did not change anything so far. The gz files are not loaded as far as I can tell. (I am using https://varvy.com/pagespeed/ to test the change)

So next I am trying to write a set of IIS rules to return the .js.gz files.
But as I am not a pro-IIS I am not having great results making it work...

This is what I have so far:

```
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Return gzip" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^.*\.(js)$" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.gz" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

But I think I need a way to change the header content-type to gzip for it to work.
Just not sure how to do it...

Answer (score 0):

> I need help to find what I am doing wrong and slows down the load time.

There are different approaches for optimizing SPA-application, including load time, bandwidth volume and performance, and stereotypical solution is creating one composite/multi-chunks bundle and optimize & compress it as possible.

But ES8+ epoch for modern browser, there is new optimal solution: using natives ES6 modules, and deploy application with such usage. See following articles: https://philipwalton.com/articles/deploying-es2015-code-in-production-today/ and https://www.contentful.com/blog/2017/04/04/es6-modules-support-lands-in-browsers-is-it-time-to-rethink-bundling/. Such approach give good performance gain and decrease server loading.